# Using Foundation in a React-static site

Tags: reactjs, webpack, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to use foundation in the react-static site I am creating. Everything is working great while using `npm start` to start a local node server with live reloading, however I am not able to successfully build my site with `npm run build`.

The error that I keep encountering is:

```
/Users/abroccoli/Documents/apm.net/apm-react-static/node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/npm.js:1
  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import $ from 'jquery';
                                                                ^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Through my research into webpack and react-static and node.js, I believe that node is having an issue with the ES6 syntax of the foundation-sites file. However, react-static is written in ES6 and uses import at the beginning of every file.

I am using the basic webpack configuration that comes with react-static and should include the proper loaders for parsing ES6 with Babel, according to the README.

```
webpack: (config, { defaultLoaders, stage }) => {
    config.module.rules = [
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
            use:
              stage === 'dev'
                ? [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, { loader: 'sass-loader' }]
                : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'css-loader',
                      options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: false,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'sass-loader',
                      options: { includePaths: ['src/'] },
                    },
                  ],
                }),
          },
          defaultLoaders.cssLoader,
          defaultLoaders.jsLoader,
          defaultLoaders.fileLoader,
        ],
      },
    ]
    return config
  },
```

I suspect that I am not loading foundation-sites in properly. How can I get foundation-sites to work when I go to build my react-static site?

Comment: What package are you using to import Foundation?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin foundation-sites@6.4.4-rc1 installed with NPM

Comment: What made you choose that over https://react.foundation/

Comment: I am using react-foundation. It's a library to be able to use foundation as react components, so you can write `<Cell large={3}></Cell>` instead of `<div className='grid-x large-3'>`. You still need to have the foundation-sites .css and .js included in your site for it to work.

Comment: I see, so how have you included the css?

Comment: Are you able to link you imports that you've used?

Comment: In my app.scss file I have ‘@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';’ in one of my components that needs the .js I have ‘import 'foundation-sites';’

Answer (score 0):

Update node to be able to use the new ES6 standard.